# How to to create / specify the AST input for testing a tree grammar with ANTLRWorks?

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

Background: I have created an ANTLR grammar. I am able to test and debug it with ANTLRWorks and have verified that the parser creates the AST that I had in my mind. Now, I want to write a tree grammar for the AST, parse the tree and debug the tree grammar with ANTLRWorks.

**Question: I want to test and debug a tree grammar with ANTLRWorks. I thus want to parse the AST that has been created by the parser. How do I specify the AST as input when testing the tree grammar with ANTLRWorks?**

P.S. 
I have studied the question / answer at [Does anyone know of a way to debug tree grammars in ANTLRWorks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561478/does-anyone-know-of-a-way-to-debug-tree-grammars-in-antlrworks) but it doesn't answer my question. Although accepted by the OP, he made a similar comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I specify the AST as input when testing the tree grammar with ANTLRWorks?

You don't need to provide the AST yourself, only the parser that produces the AST.

Given the following grammar that produces an AST:

```
grammar ASTDemo;

options { 
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  ROOT;
  U_MIN;
}

parse
 : expression EOF -> ^(ROOT expression)
 ;

expression
 : addition
 ;

addition
 : multiplication (('+' | '-')^ multiplication)*
 ;

multiplication
 : unary (('*' | '/')^ unary)*
 ;

unary
 : '-' atom -> ^(U_MIN atom)
 | atom
 ;

atom
 : ID
 | NUMBER
 | '(' expression ')' -> expression
 ;

ID     : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
NUMBER : '0'..'9'+ ('.' '0'..'9'*)?;
SPACE  : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {skip();};
```

The following would be a tree grammar for the AST produced by grammar above:

```
tree grammar ASTDemoWalker;

options {
  output=AST;
  tokenVocab=ASTDemo;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

parse
 : ^(ROOT expression)
 ;

expression
 : ^('+' expression expression)
 | ^('-' expression expression)
 | ^('*' expression expression)
 | ^('/' expression expression)
 | ^(U_MIN expression)
 | atom
 ;

atom
 : ID
 | NUMBER
 ;
```

Be sure to put both `ASTDemo.g` and `ASTDemoWalker.g` in the same folder. Open both grammars in ANTLRWorks and generate the lexer & parser from `ASTDemo.g` first by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and then generate the tree walker by opening `ASTDemoWalker.g` and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Now, from the `ASTDemoWalker.g` editor panel, fire up the debugger by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and paste the following source in the text area:

```
42 * ((a + 3) / -3.14)
```

and press <kbd>OK</kbd>.

You can now step through the debugging process and at the end, you can see both what AST the parser generated:

[image]

and how the tree walker walked over said AST:

[image]

If you now make an "accidental" mistake in the tree grammar, say, instead of `^('*' expression expression)` you define `^('*' expression)`. If you debug the tree grammar again, you will see it fail after passing the `42` node:

[image]

In the AST there is another node after the `42` node, while the tree walker expected only 1 single node (`42`) after the `*` root node.

Of course, this is an easy grammar, but even if you're familiar with ANTLR, it's sometimes a pain in the @$& to track down errors in a tree grammar! :)

Comment: Thanks again for your valuable help @Bart Kiers, I got the idea of working with both Grammar and Tree Grammar in ANTLRWorks now. - Serious, If you haven't started yet, you should write a book about ANTLR.

Comment: Thanks @ndroock1, and you're welcome of course. No, I haven't started with a book :), I think I'll stick to blogging once in a while and answering questions on SO.